# How to write events from multiple applications(sources) to the same event log?

Tags: c#, event-log, eventlog-source

I have created a custom event log and would like all my applications to write to the same event log. As you can see below in the image attached, `DistributedCOM` and `Svc Ctrl Mgr` are 2 sources writing to the same event log `System`.

[image: Multiple sources under the same log file]

Similarly, I have 2 services that I want to write to the same eventLog.
I tried doing that by creating one event log and passing different source names from the 2 Windows Services that I have created. But I find only one Service writing to the log while the other doesn't.

Below is the class library that I created for Event Log.

```
public class EventLogger
{
    private EventLog eventLog1 = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();

    public EventLogger(string logSource)
    {
        if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists(logSource))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(logSource, "SampleLog");
        }
        eventLog1.Source = logSource;
        eventLog1.Log = "SampleLog";
    }

    public void WriteLog(string message)
    {
        eventLog1.WriteEntry(message);
    }
```

Created 1st Windows Service

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    private EventLogger.EventLogger eventLog;
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        eventLog = new EventLogger.EventLogger("WinService1");
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            eventLog.WriteLog("Service started in 1st");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        eventLog.WriteLog("Service stopped");
    }
}
```

Created the 2nd windows Service as well, as above.

```
public partial class Service2 : ServiceBase
{
    private EventLogger.EventLogger eventLog;
    public Service2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        eventLog = new EventLogger.EventLogger("WinService2");
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            eventLog.WriteLog("Service started in 2nd");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        eventLog.WriteLog("Service stopped");
    }
}
```

Service1 doesn't seem to log anything, whereas, I can see the logs for Service2. I might be doing a lot of things incorrectly here. Please help me in finding a solution to this. Also, if this can be achieved by using log4Net then solutions with respect to that are welcome as well. thanks in advance.

EDIT: Also, when I try to stop the services, Service 1 fails to stop and throws an error. Image given below.

[image]

**EDIT 2**: Just changed the constructor of the `EventLogger` class as below and then it worked!! I am not entirely sure if this was the actual cause for the improper functioning. And I'm not quite sure if it had anything to do with the setting of the `Log` property either. Any light thrown on this by any one of you would be appreciated. I would like to understand better as to what exactly happened here. Thanks.

```
string logName = "NewLog";
public EventLogger(string logSource)
{
    if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists(logSource))
    {
        System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(logSource, logName);
    }
    eventLog1.Source = logSource;
}
```

Comment: Try to launch both services with administrator permissions (LOCAL_SYSTEM). Try to set `"WinService2"` source for `Service1` and `"WinService1"` source for `Service2` and see what changes.

Comment: Both the services' accounts are set to LocalSystem.